# socket.rooms returns undefined

Tags: node.js, socket.io

In my `io.on('connection')` handler I have

```
    socket.join('hell');
    console.log(socket.rooms); //prints out undefined
```

I know that `socket.rooms` is supposed to return a list of strings of all the rooms the socket has joined, but somehow in the latest version of socket.io, it doesn't.

Comment: What version of socket.io (0.9 or 1.0)? I assume this is on the server, not the client?

Comment: 1.3.6 actually, so after 1.0

Comment: How could it even be on the client?

Comment: Is what you've shown client code or server code?  `.join()` is only a server method.  It is not a client method.

Comment: Just please read my previous comment...